# Eigenvalues of a matrix which has to satisfy an equation

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

my problem is to prove that if square matrix $A$ satisfies equation $A(A-I)=0$, then each eigenvalue of $A$ is either 0 or 1.

My try:

The obvious choice is $A=0$ or $A=I$ which indeed has eigenvalues only 0 and 1 respectively. Moreover any diagonal square matrix $B$ which has only 0 or 1 on its diagonal fits the equation.

Since we know that eigenvalues of $A$ are either 0 or 1, we can assume that $A$ is a matrix of orthogonal projection in some basis, that means that any matrix $A$ which can be expressed as $A=P^{-1}BP$, where $B$ is the aforementioned diagonal matrix, has eigenvalues 0 or 1.

However I'm struggling to rigorously prove that $A$ can have eigenvalues only 0 or 1. Can anyone help me with this proof?

Comment: The basic idea is that eigenvectors $u_i$ of $A$ are also eigenvectors of $I$. You may calculate $A(A-I) u_i$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose $u$ is an eigenvector with some eigenvalue $\lambda$. Then

$A(A-I) = A^2 - A = 0$

$\implies (A^2 - A)u = 0u$

$\iff \lambda^2 u - \lambda u = 0 $

$\iff \lambda (\lambda - 1) u = 0$

This implies $\lambda (\lambda - 1) = 0 \implies \lambda \in \{0,1\}$

Answer (score 0):

Are you familiar with the minimal and the characteristic polynomials? If yes, the easier proof is that since $A(A-I)=0$, the minimal polynomial has to divide $x(x-1)$. The roots of the minimal polynomial are exactly the eigenvalues, so you are done.